# Model saving error when trying to save a model with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working through a Google Tensorflow lab - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/fraud-detection-with-bigquery-and-tensorflow-enterprise

As a step afterwards, I want to save and persist my trained model. To do so, I've been using the code:

`model.save('/home/jupyter/mymodel')`

But I hit an error:

`ValueError: ('Cannot serialize', functools.partial(<function norm_data`

This relates to the function `norm_data` in step 1 of page 5.

Can anyone give me a tip on how to resolve this? Are you not meant to embed custom functions or something?

Comment: Running into the same problem